# Hiding/showing content whether javascript is enable/disabled

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen some posts regarding wanting to do something like this, but I am at a loss to understand why my code doesn't work.  I'm trying to make sure that users who visit a page have javascript enabled.  If disabled, I want to hide all content and display a simple page with a message that the main page cannot be displayed without javascript.

I have the following:

```
<html>
  <head><title>my site</title>
  <noscript><style type="text/css">site {display:none;} </style></noscript>
  </head>
  <body onload="hideDiv()">
    <div id="noscriptmsg">You need to have javascript enabled in order to view this site.</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("noscriptmsg").style.display = 'none';</script>
  </body>
  <body>
    <div class="site">
    <!--content -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Currently this shows the correct javascript-enabled page, but a completely blank javascript-disabled page.  What would cause this?

Comment: Your class selector is missing the period. Should be `.site {display:none;}`, Also not sure if noscript tag should be in the head.

Comment: `body onload="hideDiv()"` is dependent on Javascript being present.

Comment: @DavidTansey, that's the point.  If javascript is disabled, that will not run, and the `div` should show.

Comment: Hide your content by default, and have JavaScript show it.  This feels backwards.

Comment: Also, two [`<body>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) tags? Not wise. Use two container elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the build in `noscript` in one `body` tag:

```
<html>
  <head><title>my site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <style type="text/css">
          #site {display:none;}
      </style>
      <div id="noscriptmsg">
        You need to have javascript enabled in order to view this site.
      </div>
    </noscript>

    <div id="site">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall,  just noticed that, thanks for the update

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in the body onload you are trying to call the method hideDiv()

First, I'd recommend moving your script tag

```
<html>
  <head><title>my site</title>
  <noscript><style type="text/css">.site {display:none;} </style></noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">
// to the head tag
// and define the hideDiv() method
function hideDiv() {
        document.getElementById("noscriptmsg").style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body onload="hideDiv()">
    <div id="noscriptmsg">You need to have javascript enabled in order to view this site.</div>
    <div class="site">
    <!--content -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and remove the extraneous body tags. You can use css to have the first div (the one with the notice) display at 100% width and 100% height. Also, someone pointed out you were missing the css class selector.

Comment: do you mean to have a </script> tag before the </head> ?